# Ghostly mouse trail after upgrading 19.04 to 20.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, mouse

Since upgrading to 20.04 I've been getting a ghostly mouse trail on my desktop. I found [this...](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/meta-gnome3/+bug/1872870/comments/3)

> *I have the exact same problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from
> Ubuntu 18.04. I have found that **the issue goes away when I disable zoom**
> in Settings -> Universal Access. This was never an issue in Ubuntu 18.04
> for me with zoom enabled. At least now I know I can work around this
> issue by just turning off zoom but it'd be great if there was a real fix
> for this issue.*

...and disabling zoom does indeed make the problem go away. Obviously that's not a "fix", since I enabled the zoom feature in the first place so I could ***use*** it. But I tend to think if there are *visible* signs of "unexpected behaviour", there may also be associated ***invisible*** things going wrong (potentially damaging totally unrelated parts of my system).

What should I do? Is there a bug-free alternative to the Ubuntu standard Zoom facility?